# TOAD-Modify Materialized View Select Query without dropping

Tags: oracle10g, toad, materialized-views

Is there any way I can edit the MVIEW query without dropping it in TOAD.I am not sure if we can do it?If not how Can I do it in a way that does not affect the table contents?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can't alter a materialized view query, you have to drop and recreate it.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_2001.htm

> Use the ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW statement to modify an existing
>   materialized view in one or more of the following ways:
>
> - To change its storage characteristics
> - To change its refresh method, mode, or time
> - To alter its structure so that it is a different type of materialized
>     view
> - To enable or disable query rewrite

Comment: So I will need to get the exact DDL used for that MVIEW and drop my old and recreate it?right?So the data already in the old MVIEW will be dropped as well?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I said. I'm not sure what you think the db could do - if you change the query, the data is no longer correct.

Comment: Yes I agree.In case I drop it..Will I be able to recreate it with same name.I need the same name or I will have to rename the old one.

Comment: Yes, you can use the same name.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jeffre Kemp, you cannot change the query of an existing Materialized View.

However, if you expect that changes will be necessary in the future, you can choose one of these approaches:

- use an intermediate VIEW that does all the heavy lifting; your MATERIALIZED VIEW then does a simple `SELECT * FROM myView`. This allows you to change the query - however, it does not allow you to add / remove columns to/from the MATERIALIZED VIEW
- use a pre-built table for your materialized view; this logically separates the TABLE that holds the content from the query that is used to update the content. Now, you can drop the MATERIALIZED VIEW, add/remove columns from your TABLE as needed, and re-create the MATERIALIZED VIEW afterwards
- use a synonym for all code that queries the MATERIALIZED VIEW; if necessary, create a backup table using CTAS, point the synonym to this backup table, drop and re-create your MATERIALIZED VIEW, point the synonym back to the MATERIALIZED VIEW, and drop your backup table (that's how we do it)